# Standadise Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to standardize a numpy array. I seem to be doing something wrong as the value of some elements of the output array is incorrect. I'd appreciate any help. Please find the code below:
PYTHON CODE:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import numpy as np
import math


class matrix(object):
    """A matrix class."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.array_2d = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])

    def standardise(self):
        rows, columns = self.array_2d.shape
        temp = self.array_2d
        for j in range(columns):
            for i in range(rows):
                self.array_2d[i,j] = (temp[i, j] - min(temp[:, j])) / (max(temp[:, j]) - min(temp[:, j]))



m = matrix()
print(m.array_2d, "\n")
m.standardise()
print(m.array_2d)
```

Comment: can you add the desired output?

Comment: `temp = self.array_2d` doesn't make a copy of `array_2d`: it just makes the name `temp` point to the same array.  So in your `for` loop, `temp` points to the same array that you've been changing in previous iterations of the loop, not to the original array.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is just to scale the matrix you dont have to do it in a for loop. You can do like this because Numpy is vectorized by default.

```
a =  np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
scaled_a = (a - a.min(axis=1))/(a.max(axis=1) - a.min(axis=1))
```